# How to validate a string that contains 4 letter not including '.' character?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to validate a textfield value in order to have maximum 4 characters not including '.' character.

```
<v-text-field 
   v-model="diagnoseCode" 
   style="height: 38px"
   outlined 
   dense 
   maxLength="4">
</v-text-field>
```

I have tried this, but this doesnt take into account checking for '.' character.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  You may not be aware (yet)...but there are guidelines for asking a question...and if you don't follow them...folks will begin to vote-down your reputation.  To prevent this: You will need to show more effort in the form of sample code.  Sample data would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method to set max length:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      diagnoseCode: null,
      max: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clear() {
      this.max = null
    },
    check(e) {
      str = this.diagnoseCode
      if (str.replaceAll('.', '').length > 4 && !this.diagnoseCode.endsWith('.')) {
        this.diagnoseCode = this.diagnoseCode.slice(0,-1)
        this.max = this.diagnoseCode.length
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field v-model="diagnoseCode"
                      style="height: 38px"
                      outlined 
                      dense 
                      :maxLength="max"
                      @keyup="check($event.target.value)"
                      @keydown="clear">
        </v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like your check function means to cause a side-effect on the model, but it doesn't make an assignment.

Comment: Yes it works but there is a problem, if I write 4 characters, for example '1234' it doesnt allow me to write numbers after that string...

Comment: @ Mina hey, wasn't that your requirement max 4 chars excluding '.'?

Comment: yes but it must not take into account '.' even if it comes after '1234' for example. It doesnt allow me to write '.' after this string '1234'

Comment: ok, check now pls, I updated answer

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, cheers :)